# How to get an attribute value from custom tag in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I`m trying to make own flexible password component in angular5. I should get min-max attribute values to validate password and can't get it.

I`ve tried to get value using js(getAttribute), but it doesn't work.

```
<password
                    [id]="passwordFieldId"
                    title="Password field"
                    placeholder="Enter a password"
                    [isValid]="isPasswordFieldValid"
                    [isDisabled]="isPasswordFieldDisabled"
                    [isRequired]="true"
                    type="password"
                    [minlength]= '5'
                    [maxlength] = '10'
                    [formControlName]="passwordFieldId"
                    [errorText]="errorText">
</password>



 public ngOnInit() {

        this.form = new FormGroup({
            [this.passwordFieldId]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(/** i don`t know what should i write here */), Validators.maxLength(/** i don`t know what should i write here */)])
        });
    }
```

---

```
   public maxLength = this.form.get(this.passwordFieldId).get('maxlength');
```

gives me undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `maxlength` using the component reference :

From the template :

```
<password
 #passwordInput
 [id]="passwordFieldId"
...


{{ passwordInput.maxlength | json }}
```

From the component class using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) :

```
@ViewChild('passwordInput', { static: false }) password;
...

logValues() {
    console.log(this.password.maxlength);
}
```

[Here is a running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57671055)

Comment: Thanks. It`s really useful

Answer (score 0):

Here am showing a demo form in Angular. Hope this will help you

Ts File
1.Import

```
import{FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
```

2.Inside the Class
form :FormGroup;
3.Inside Constrctor

```
constructor() {

 this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
      passwordFieldId:['',Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(6)])]
});
}
```

4.In HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input type="password" formControlName="passwordFieldId" >
<button (click)="getPsw()"></button>
</form>
```

5.In Ts

```
getPsw() {
console.log(this.form.passwordFieldId.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to make it so complex? You can just define two global variables in the component:

```
public minlength: number = 5;
public maxlength: number = 10;
```

And use them both in your template

```
<password [minlength]="minlength" [maxlength]="maxlength"
</password>
```

and component:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
            [this.passwordFieldId]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minlength), Validators.maxLength(this.maxlength)])
        });
```